# SystemJs: Load file from different directory

Tags: javascript, systemjs

I have `app/owner/index.html` and `app/shared/order.js`. I'm trying to import `order.js` using SystemJs. In `index.html` I have the following:

`<script>System.import('app/shared/order.js').catch(function(err) {console.error("Got an error. Here it is: " + err);});`

but when I try and load the page I get the following error

`Got me an error. Here it is: Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/app/shared/order.js`

If I put move `order.js` such that `app/owner/order.js` and use the following in `index.html`

`<script>System.import('app/owner/order.js').catch(function(err) {console.error("Got an error. Here it is: " + err);});`

it works. So where could I be going wrong with `app/shared/order.js`?

Comment: Is `http://localhost:3000/app/shared/order.js` opens if you put it in your address bar?

Comment: Just to make sure is shared publicly accessible? (e.g when you open http://localhost:3000/app/shared/order.js in your browser you can see the contents of the script?)

Comment: no i can't. I'm new to web stuff. How would I go about making it publicly accessible? Do I have to set express to do this?

Comment: Okay. Understand now. Added `expressServer.use('/app/shared', express.static(__dirname + '/../app/shared'))` to my server. This web stuff slowly starting to make sense. Either above care to answer I shall mark up as you pointed me in right direction.